# Device not registered in pushwoosh

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, trigger.io, pushwoosh

I am using the pushwoosh to register the device via my trigger.io app.

This is my device registration code

[image]

I will trigger this code everytime my app starts.

According to the documentation, I need to define the code differently for IOS and Android, hence the 2 lines. (Not sure if it is correct).

However after I run the app and register a new user on IOS, the subscriber count in my pushwoosh did not seem to increase.

I have already uploaded the relevant apple certs and apns p12 files in pushwoosh.

IOS platform configuration page in pushwoosh
[image]

IOS platform device count did not increase after I start the app of a new user.
[image]

Does anyone know if there is any missing setup I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seemed to have been resolved after I created a new application in pushwoosh.